How should I show this with the signum function? (Please check my work.)
Show that $\operatorname{sgn}(\sin\theta)\sin^2\theta=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin((2k-1)\theta)}{(2k-1)(3+4k-4k^2)}$.
Here's my work: Proof:
By definition, the signum function of the real variable $x$ is defined as $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=1$ for $x>0$, $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=0$ for $x=0$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(x)=-1$ for $x<0$.
If $f(x)$ is a function of the real variable $x$ such that the integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx$ exists and if the Fourier coefficients $(a_{n}, b_{n})$ are defined by $a_{n}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos nx dx, n=0, 1, ...,$ and $b_{n}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin nx dx, n=1, 2, ...,$ then the Fourier series of $f(x)$ is the periodic function $F(x)=\frac{1}{2}a_{0}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n}\cos nx+b_{n}\sin nx)$.
Let $f(\theta)=\operatorname{sgn}(\sin\theta)\sin^2\theta$.
Then $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\operatorname{sgn}(\sin\theta)\sin^2\theta d\theta=[\frac{1}{2}(\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta)\operatorname{sgn}(\sin\theta)]_{-\pi}^{\pi}=0$ because $\operatorname{sgn}(\sin\pi)=0$ and $\operatorname{sgn}(\sin(-\pi))=0$.
Note that $a_{0}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta)\cos 0 d\theta=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}sgn(\sin\theta)\sin^2\theta d\theta=\frac{1}{\pi}(0)=0$.
This gives $a_{k}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta)\cos k\theta d\theta=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\operatorname{sgn}(\sin\theta)\sin^2\theta\cos k\theta d\theta=0$ for all $n$ because $f(\theta)=\operatorname{sgn}(\sin\theta)\sin^2\theta$ is an odd function and $\cos k\theta$ is an even function.
Hence, $F(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}a_{0}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_{k}\cos k\theta+b_{k}\sin k\theta)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_{k}\sin k\theta$ where $b_{k}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta)\sin k\theta d\theta$ for $k=1, 2, ... . $
Up to here, how should I evaluate and find $b_{k}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\operatorname{sgn}(\sin\theta)\sin^2\theta\cdot\sin k\theta d\theta$ in order to show that $\operatorname{sgn}(\sin\theta)\sin^2\theta=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin((2k-1)\theta)}{(2k-1)(3+4k-4k^2)}$?

just a suggestion on MathJax, consider using for the sign function the command \text{sgn}(x) as $\text{sgn}(x)$ instead of $sgn(x)$

@Joako While this is good advice, \operatorname{} is better as it preserves the proper spacing. You will notice a subtle difference between $\text{sgn}(x)$  (\text{sgn}(x)) and $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$   (\operatorname{sgn}(x)) .

Okay, got it. Now I know.

Note that showing the right side is the Fourier series for the left side is not sufficient to prove the equality. The Fourier series does not necessarily converge to the function.

So how would you show/prove this?

Your function is $2\pi$-periodic and $\mathcal C^1$ so you have point wise convergence of the Fourier series:
$$
f(\theta) = a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos(2\pi n\theta)+b_n\sin(2\pi n\theta)
$$
Since $f$ is odd:
$$
f(-\theta) = -f(\theta)
$$
you are left only with the $\sin$ terms (i.e. $a_n=a_0=0$) and furthermore, since it is odd at $\pi$:
$$
f(2\pi-\theta) = -f(\theta)
$$
you can further restrict to terms of odd $n=2k-1$ (i.e. $b_{2k}=0$) for $k\in\mathbb N^*$. You therefore just need to compute:
$$
\begin{align}
b_{2k-1} &= \frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(\theta)\sin[(2k-1)\theta]d\theta \\
&= \frac4\pi\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2\theta\sin[(2k-1)\theta]d\theta \\
\end{align}
$$
The usual method is to linearise:
$$
\begin{align}
\sin^2\theta\sin[(2k-1)\theta] &= \frac12[1-\cos(2\theta)]\sin[(2k-1)\theta] \\
&= \frac14(2\sin[(2k-1)\theta]-\sin[(2k+1)\theta]-\sin[(2k-3)\theta])
\end{align}
$$
so:
$$
\begin{align}
b_{2k-1} &= \frac1\pi\int_0^{\pi/2} (2\sin[(2k-1)\theta]-\sin[(2k+1)\theta]-\sin[(2k-3)\theta])d\theta \\
&= \frac1\pi\left[-\frac{2\cos[(2k-1)\theta]}{2k-1}+\frac{\cos[(2k+1)\theta]}{2k+1}+\frac{\cos[(2k-3)\theta]}{2k-3}\right]_0^{\pi/2} \\
&= -\frac1\pi\left(-\frac2{2k-1}+\frac1{2k+1}+\frac1{2k-3}\right)
\end{align}
$$

May you please take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4989363/how-should-i-show-that-all-solutions-of-the-equation-are-bounded-and-periodic ? Thank you so much for your help.
